# Delete lines from one file that exist in another using python

Tags: python, jython

I have two files - file_1 and file_2. I need to lookup all the lines from file_1 against all lines in file_2 and if I found any matches, delete the matched line from file_1 using a python code. For e.g.

Contents of file_1:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Contents of file_2:

```
a
c
```

I'm expecting to see the updated contents of file_1 as below since a and c exist in file_2:

```
b
d
e
```

I'm tried opening the files and put the contents of both the files in two different lists intending to do a minus but kinda stuck here. Could you please throw me some pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way, but try this:

```
# read both files
with open('file_one.txt') as f:
    file_one = f.read().splitlines()

with open('file_two.txt') as f:
    file_two = f.read().splitlines()

# method 1 by stephan berger:
result = list(set(file_one)^set(file_two))

# method 2:
for idx_one, line_one in enumerate(file_one):
    for idx_two, line_two in enumerate(file_two):
        if line_two == line_one:
            print(f"Removing duplicate: {line_two}")
            file_one.pop(idx_one)

# write new file
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in result:  # file_one for method 2
        f.write(line + "\n")
print("Generated output.txt")
```

Comment: I tried method 1 and it works just fine. However, the file_1 contents are not sorted in the same order as they were before.

Comment: Replace `for line in result:` with `for line in sorted(result):`

Comment: With the given code file_one is only read, and not overwritten at any point. If you want to overwrite file_one you have to replace `with open("output.txt", "w") as f:` with `with open("file_one.txt", "w") as f:`. I think you are mixing up your output.txt and file_one.txt.

Comment: Another observation is - the first run does work as expected.  But when I run it again, the content of file_1 should not change. However, the file_1 is going back to its original version. Looks like, the first run is deleting the common contents and 2nd run is adding back the missing ones. So I used minus between the sets instead of ^ and that worked.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted the result to be written back to file_1.

Answer (score 1):

places the elements of each file in 2 lists l1 and l2.

And use sets:

result = list(set(l1)^set(l2))

Comment: much nicer than the two iterations i made :) edited my code